# "Ruff" Geometric Problem: Dog tethered to hexagonal doghouse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, recreational-mathematics

This story problem pertains to both geometry and algebra.

> A dog has a dog house shaped like a regular hexagon with a base that measures $2$ yards on each side. The dog is tethered to one of the angles with a $4$ yard rope.
>
> What is the area in square yards that the dog can reach?

I have attempted this problem twice, but each time end up with outrageous answers. I know that I must calculate the area that the dog can walk first, using $4$ as the **circumference**(?) of the circle. Once I complete this step I get lost. All help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: radius not circumference perhaps... ? and on what type of surface ? is the dog a point ?

Comment: See the newly attached picture

Comment: so what's your issue ?

Comment: I have the same doubt as Roddy MacPhee: why are you taking $4$ as the circumference? I left it as you originally typed it in my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the sketch the OP provides, I shall interpret the problem as the leash will trace out a circle of **radius** $4$ until it hits one side of the doghouse.

The side length of the doghouse is denoted as $\ell = 2$.

For visual clarify, the diagram below shows only the upper half of the "grazing" region.

\begin{align}
\text{total area} &= \text{twice of}~\Bigl(\text{one third large disc (green)} + \text{one sixth small disc (purple)} \Bigr) \\
&= 2 \left( \frac13 \pi R^2 + \frac16 \pi r^2\right) \qquad \text{, with}~R = 4 ~~,~~ r = R-\ell  = 2 \\
&=2 \pi \left( \frac{16}3 + \frac46 \right) \\
&= 12 \pi
\end{align}
To see that the discs are a third and a sixth, simply note that the doghouse is hexagonal and the relevant angles are $2\pi/3$ and $\pi/3$, respectively. There's not a third disc because $r - \ell = 0$. 
[image]

Comment: also depends on if the length of the dog is included ... if its hind legs count with assumed length 1yd , you might be able to get almost around the rest of it. gives a nicer answer of $20\pi$  but neglects the dogs thickness.

Comment: Yes, I will have to modify my answer if OP updates the question with such info.